# how to apply horizontal and vertical scroll bars by using jquery Tiny Scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

Is there any way to apply both horizontal and vertical scroll bars by using jquery Tiny Scrollbar plugin.

javascript code is :

```
 $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
```

link of the tutorial : http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

Answer (score 0):

This plugin does not support it.

A list of all the available options and there default value

A list of all the available options and there default value

> axis: 'x' -- Vertical or horizontal scroller? 'x' or 'y' .
>
> wheel: 40 -- How many pixels must the mouswheel scroll at a time .
>
> scroll: true -- Enable or disable the mousewheel.
>
> lockscroll: true -- Return scrollwheel to browser if there is no more
>   content.
>
> size: 'auto' -- Set the size of the scrollbar to auto or a fixed
>   number.
>
> sizethumb: 'auto' -- Set the size of the thumb to auto or a fixed
>   number.
>
> invertscroll: false -- Enable mobile invert style scrolling.

**So you CAN NOT set both X and Y axis**

I looked through code and i can say that this plugin minimazed code and achive only goals that are declard in spec, and using of ONLY one axis is hardcoded. In order to achive possibility to work with two axises you need rewrite this plugin. It could take much time, it is not trivial/easy task.

Comment: is there any way to change the plugin code to get both scroll bars to work.

Comment: I put aswuer on your question in body

Comment: Well you could use 2 tinyscrollbar instances. However i never tested it so not sure if it works correctly. Will try to make a demo.